# OctoberCMS: Manage a two-way many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I am trying to design a dictionary. The tables are:

```sql
-- Languages
create table meysam_dictionary_languages
(
    id int unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    title varchar(50) not null
)

-- Words
create table meysam_dictionary_words
(
    id int unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    word varchar(500) not null,
    lang_id int unsigned not null
)

-- Translations
create table meysam_dictionary_translations
(
    left_word_id int unsigned not null,
    right_word_id int unsigned not null,
    description varchar(500) not null
)
```

Now each `Word` could have many meanings. Therefore there is a many-to-many relationship between words. This relation is stored in the `Translations` table. Here is my `Word` model:

```php
class Word extends Model
{
    public $belongsTo = [
        'language' => [
            'Meysam\Dictionary\Models\Language',
            'key' => 'lang_id'
        ]
    ];

    public $belongsToMany = [
        'meanings' => [
            'Meysam\Dictionary\Models\Word',
            'table'    => 'meysam_dictionary_translations',
            'key'      => 'left_word_id',
            'otherKey' => 'right_word_id'
        ],
    ];
}
```

Given the above `$belongsToMany` relationship, in the `Word` controller page, I can only see the meanings of a word if the word ID is on the left side of the relation in the `Translations` table. But if the word is on the right side of the relationship, its related words will not be shown. Is there any workaround for this?

I need the related words of a word to be shown in the controller page regardless of that word being on the left or right side of the relationship in the `Translations` table.

Answer (score 0):

it's a matter of adapting your query (query either if it's the `key` or `otherKey` equal to your word id), just implement the rule `key < otherKey` and you will gain unicity.

Take a look at this article using the same method to declare relation between two users.
[Social network](https://www.codedodle.com/2014/12/social-network-friends-database.html)

In that example, you'll not be needing the "action" field.

The query would look like this

```php
$languageId = 1;
$wordId = 1;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM words RIGHT JOIN (SELECT `key`, other_key FROM `meysam_dictionary_translations` WHERE (`key` = '.$wordId.' OR `other_key` = '.$wordId.') AND language_id = '.$languageId.') as r on words.id = r.key OR words.id = r.other_key WHERE workds.id!='.$wordId
```